# Weird l/r/trim() behaviour

Tags: php

I'm experiencing an issue that `trim('/','/musla-ktora-lieci/');` returns an empty string. It works in the same way with all trim functions - `trim()`, `ltrim()` and `rtrim()`.

PHP:

```
PHP 5.5.20 (cli) (built: Feb 25 2015 23:30:53) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

```
trim('/','/musla-ktora-lieci/');
```

For Heaven's sake those parameters are in wrong order

> string trim ( string $str [, string $character_mask = " \t\n\r\0\x0B" ] )

And

> What am I doing wrong?

Not reading the  **[manual](http://php.net/trim)**  in case of any unexpected behavior.

```
echo trim('/musla-ktora-lieci/','/');   // musla-ktora-lieci
```

Comment: Don't you just love the ones that read the manuals through.

Comment: Yep sure do, specially when something doesn't work as expected.

Comment: What better time to not consult the manual when it doesn't work. Who would've thought the creators would actually tell you how to use these functions. Revolutionary stuff here !